# Solution architecture diagram - arrow directions

Tags: architecture, diagram

There are different types of arrows used in software architecture diagrams.

For ex. there are two applications A and B. What is the difference between the following -

1. Single bi-directional arrow between A and B
2. Two arrows in parallel between A and B, one pointing to A and the other to B

Do they mean the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrows depicts interaction and flow of information:

Both have same meaning, it depends on how much information you want to cover in diagram, sometimes it is important to write on arrow some details about information flowing, so choosing two is better.

Hope this helps.

Cheers !!

Comment: If bi-directional arrow shows "one way" of information, then what does single direction arrow mean?